# Write Pajek files with node labels using python-igraph

Tags: python, igraph

I am constructing graphs using `igraph` and writing them out as Pajek (`.net`) files to use them with another program. The Pajek files are written with numerical indices for vertices rather than vertex labels, so when I read the files into the other program, the labels are gone.

Here's a simple example:

```
>>> g = ig.Graph(vertex_attrs={'label': ['spam', 'eggs', 'ham']}, edges=[(1,0), (1,2)])
>>> g.vs.get_attribute_values('label')
['spam', 'eggs', 'ham']
>>> g.write_pajek('file.net')

$ head file.net
*Vertices 3
*Edges
1 2
2 3
```

Is it possible to change the behavior of `write_pajek()` to write out the labels instead of just the indices?

---

A kind colleague pointed out that the underlying `igraph` C library [doesn't have](https://github.com/igraph/igraph/blob/5cea4789827c9da2b424b65246d3b7d9642741e1/src/foreign.c#L2039) the ability to write out vertex labels.

Here's a workaround:

```
import igraph as ig
g = ig.Graph(vertex_attrs={'label': ['spam', 'eggs', 'ham']}, edges=[(1,0), (1,2)])
g.write_gml('file.gml')

import networkx as nx
n = nx.read_gml('file.gml')
nx.write_pajek(n, 'nxfile.net')

$ head nxfile.net
*vertices 3
0 0 0.0 0.0 ellipse label spam id 0
1 1 0.0 0.0 ellipse label eggs id 1
2 2 0.0 0.0 ellipse label ham id 2
...
```

---

**Update**

No workaround needed! Thanks to Gabor for pointing out that `write_pajek()` uses the `id` attribute, not the `label` attribute.

```
>>> g.vs['id'] = g.vs['label'] 
>>> g.write_pajek('igfile.net') 

$ head igfile.net 
*Vertices 3 
1 "spam" 
2 "eggs" 
3 "ham" 
*Edges 
1 2 
2 3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You colleague is kind, but (s)he is still wrong. :) The right attribute to set is called `id`:

```
g = ig.Graph(vertex_attrs={'id': ['spam', 'eggs', 'ham']}, edges=[(1,0), (1,2)])
```

(I haven't actually tried this in Python, because I am having a hard time installing python-igraph. But it works fine from R and they are calling the same C code, so I am 99% sure that it works in Python as well. Could you try it?)

Comment: Amazing. That did it!